# Calculate the cost per square of a circular object

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, geometry

I am trying to calculate the cost per square of a circular object, given its diameter and price.

Here is what I got:

```
import math

def main():
    print("This program calculates the cost per square inch of a circular object.")

    diameter = eval(input("What is the diameter of the object? "))
    price = eval(input("What is the price of the whole object? "))

    cost_per_square = (math.pi * (diameter / 2)**2) / price

    print("The cost per square inch is $", round(cost_per_square, 2), sep="")

main()
```

I'm not good at math, so I wondered if the formula is correct ?

Comment: I would like to warn you against eval(input()) calls - the user can input some valid python code and it will be executed in the process of evaluation.  It is much safer to use float(input())

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of that, I've just begun Python.

Comment: Both eval and exec will execute any string given them, (eval expecting the result to be a value).  This is very powerful when your code is generating code and then running it for you __but__ when someone _else_ can supply the string it is also ___incredibly dangerous___ so you need to avoid calling them on anything that comes from the outside world.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Comment: Math?  This is a *high school algebra formula*.    The issue is very much a programming problem, not math, if you actually read the code.

Comment: @onimoj: Concerning @SteveBarnes's misgivings: In case you ever switch to Python2.x keep in mind that `input` there will evaluate itself (and you have to use `raw_input` to prevent that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the formula for the area of a circle is A = π * r * r.

But `price` should be in the numerator and `area` in the denominator.  You've coded the *inverse* - square feet per unit cost.  Think of the units you want: cost per square foot.  That will guide you.

I'd recommend dividing `diameter` by 2.0 rather than 2 to avoid issues with integer division.

Comment: If you use π, you should not be afraid of using ² ;-)

Comment: Afraid?  No, just ignorant.  Not on the tip of my tongue.  What's the markup?  Please edit.  I'm too lazy to Google.

Comment: I type just `compose key` `^` `2` to get it.  I know no markup for that.

Comment: @duffymo I couldn't accept it because it was too recent. Now it is ok :)

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest to compute intermediate values with proper names first.  This often prevents mistakes in the first place:

```
radius = diameter / 2.0
area = math.pi * radius**2
price_per_area = price / area
```

You also might have noticed that I preferred "price" before "cost" and "area" before "square".  That's because using synonyms interchangeably also introduces room for errors.  All three lines now are so simple that it will be hard to introduce the error you first made.

Comment: +1 - good names matter.  Great point.  Just one quibble: Divide diameter by 2.0 to avoid integer division issue.

Comment: @duffymo - agreed, good names matter tremendously. One meta-quibble, the question is specifically marked python-3 where `5/2 == 2.5` but for portability and readability your recommendation is probably good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The formula to find area of circle is `pi*r*r`. To get the cost per square inch, do this: `price / area`